# Open SKScene from storyboard

Tags: interface-builder, swift, sprite-kit, xcode6, xcode-storyboard

From the Main.storyboard generated when making a new SpriteKit iOS game, I made a simple main menu with a play game button using Interface Builder. However, I am trying to make it so when that button is pressed it opens a new SKScene, which I don't want to build with Interface Builder. I have it so when the button is pressed it opens that scene, and the scene has functionality, but the menu GUI remains over the scene, and I want to just clear the Interface Builder menu and have a clear SKScene. I've tried making the storyboard lead to a new view controller to present the scene, and that resulted in a handful of errors, which I did not understand; it stopped and just said (lldb) in the log. I am not sure if I can link a new storyboard view to the scene or just use

```
 @IBAction func onPlayPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    println("play pressed")
    (self.view as SKView).presentScene(GameScene(size: self.view.bounds.size))
 }
```

to call clear GUI and present the scene

I am new to Xcode and swift so if i apologize if this is a simple question, but I could not find any information on how to do this.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

After trying a few different things, I was able to make it enter a new blank view controller from the storyboard which the button led to, then clear the storyboard view and present the scene. In the second view controller I added

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

before presenting the SKScene